# How to set a location of point using Point class?

Tags: java, swing, point

I am trying to set a location of geometric figure that appears in JFrame window. For example if it's a rectangle so i need to move it's left upper point 10 pixels right, and left lower point 10 pixels down.

I was trying to do like this but it didn't work:

```
public void relocate(ArrayList<MyShape> newShape){

    int x1, x2, y1 , y2;

    for(int i = 0; i < newShape.size(); i++){

        x1 = (int)newShape.get(i).p1.getX();
        y1 = (int)newShape.get(i).p1.getY();

        x2 = (int)newShape.get(i).p2.getX();
        y2 = (int)newShape.get(i).p2.getY();


        newShape.get(i).setLocation(x1 + 10, y1);
        newShape.get(i).setP1(newShape.get(i).getP1());
        newShape.get(i).setLocation(x2, y2 + 10);
        newShape.get(i).setP2(newShape.get(i).getP2());


        if(newShape.get(i).getCol() != null){
            newShape.get(i).setCol(Color.BLUE);
        }


    }

    repaint();
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it didn't work"? What exactly happens here, and how does it differ from your desired outcome?

Comment: And hint: what is MyShape. Please keep in mind: no wizards here. We don't know what your code is doing; unless you share it with us!

Comment: the point of geometric shape doesn't move 10 pixels right on the left and 10 pixels down on the left.

Comment: MyShape is a supper class for all the shapes.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work - in a sense that it changes the location of the objects on the screen. So, what's going on here? What's wrong with your solution?

I can give you a few hints though:

You can check if any other part of the code is messing with the location setting. It's possible that they override your settings.

Maybe this code runs outside of the AWT Thread. You can check it with `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()`.

You can reuse the `Point`-s in Swing. Points are mutable object. This leads to not so clean code, but performance is important in this case:

```
MyShape shape = newShape.get(i);
Point p = shape.getP1();
p.setLocation(p.x, p.y + 10);
```

Maybe a `revalidate()` call can help too:

```
public void relocate(ArrayList<MyShape> newShape) {
    // some code changing locations
    revalidate(); // this is it
    repatint();
}
```

Comment: a revalidate() is not necessary. A revalidate() is only used to invoke the layout manager.

Answer (score 1):

The following analysis is based on assumptions about how MyShape works since you've declined to provide those details when asked for them.

Look at your algorithm.  For each shape:

1) You're capturing the original values of P1 and P2.  So far so good.

2) You're calling the shape's `setLocation()` method with an adjusted value for P1.  *Now, what does `setLocation()` do?*  Understanding that is part of why you were asked about the MyShape class, and saying it's a superclass for all shapes doesn't help.

3) You tell the shape to set its P1 to whatever value you get by querying its P1.  If the getters and setters do anything reasonable, this won't do anything.

4) You then call `setLocation()` again, this time with an adjusted value for P2.  *Again, what does this do?*  It probably undoes whatever you accomplished in step 2.

5) You tell the shape to set its P2 to whatever value you get by querying its P2.  Again, this probably doesn't do anything.

What you want to do, I assume, is set P1 based on the adjusted values you calculated in step 2; and set P2 based on the adjusted values in step 4.  But that's not what your code says unless secLocation, getP1, and getP2 are all doing very ununtuitive things.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what `MyShape` does, but it seems that `newShape.get(i).setP1` just overrides `newShape.get(i).setLocation` right before it. Try adjusting your code like this:

```
//Change this
newShape.get(i).setLocation(x1 + 10, y1);
newShape.get(i).setP1(newShape.get(i).getP1());
newShape.get(i).setLocation(x2, y2 + 10);
newShape.get(i).setP2(newShape.get(i).getP2());
//To this
newShape.get(i).getP1().setLocation(x1 + 10, y1);
newShape.get(i).getP2().setLocation(x2, y2 + 10);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: (1-) already suggested by Tamas 15 minutes earlier. No need to repeat suggestions.

Comment: To be fair, I didn't elaborate further and just adjusted to code to OP his or her needs, I didn't introduce the entire `Point` class or went further into the structure of swing. But I understand if you consider it too similar.